# Read the data from a text file and reshape the data in R

Tags: r

I have a data set for different time intervals. The data has three comment lines before data for each time interval. For each time interval there are 500 data points. I want to change the dataset such that I have the following format:

```
t1  t2  t3   ................
0.00208 0.00417 0.00625 .................
a1  a2  a3 ...................
b1  b2  b3 ...................
c1  c2  c3 .................
...............................
................................
```

The link to the file is as follows: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hc8n3qcai1mlxca/WAT_DEP.DAT

As you will see on the file, time for each interval is the second data of the third line before the data starts. For the first time, t= 0.00208. I need to change the data in several rows into one column. At last I need to create a dataframe with the format shown above. In the sample above, a1, b1, c1 are the data for time t1, and so on.

I am sorry for posting a relatively large data set.

Thank you for the help.

**Sample data added**

The sample data is as follows:

```
** N:SNAPSHOT    TIME      DELT[S]
** WATER DEPTH [M]: (HP(L),L=2,LA)
      1800        0.00208   0.10000
     3.224     3.221     3.220     3.217     3.216     3.214     3.212     3.210     3.209     3.207
     3.205     3.203     3.202     3.200     3.199     3.197     3.196     3.193     3.192     3.190
     3.189     3.187     3.186     3.184     3.184     3.182     3.181     3.179     3.178     3.176
     3.175     3.174     3.173     3.171     3.170     3.169     3.168     3.167     3.166     3.164
     3.164     3.162     3.162     3.160     3.160     3.158     3.158     3.156     3.156     3.155
     3.154     3.153     3.152     3.151     3.150     3.150     3.149     3.149     3.147     3.147
     3.146     3.146     3.145     3.145     3.144     3.144     3.143     3.143     3.142     3.142
     3.141     3.142     3.141     3.141     3.140     3.141     3.140     3.140     3.139     3.140
     3.139     3.140     3.139     3.140     3.139     3.140     3.139     3.140     3.139     3.140
     3.139     3.140     3.140     3.140     3.140     3.141     3.141     3.142     3.141     3.142
     3.142     3.142     3.143     3.143     3.144     3.144     3.145     3.145     3.146     3.146
     3.147     3.148     3.149     3.149     3.150     3.150     3.152     3.152     3.153     3.154
     3.155     3.156     3.157     3.158     3.159     3.160     3.161     3.162     3.163     3.164
     3.165     3.166     3.168     3.169     3.170     3.171     3.173     3.174     3.176     3.176
     3.178     3.179     3.181     3.182     3.184     3.185     3.187     3.188     3.190     3.191
     3.194     3.195     3.196     3.198     3.199     3.202     3.203     3.205     3.207     3.209
     3.210     3.213     3.214     3.217     3.218     3.221     3.222     3.225     3.226     3.229
     3.231     3.233     3.235     3.238     3.239     3.242     3.244     3.247     3.248     3.251
     3.253     3.256     3.258     3.261     3.263     3.266     3.268     3.271     3.273     3.276
     3.278     3.281     3.283     3.286     3.289     3.292     3.294     3.297     3.299     3.303
     3.305     3.307     3.311     3.313     3.317     3.319     3.322     3.325     3.328     3.331
     3.334     3.337     3.340     3.343     3.347     3.349     3.353     3.356     3.359     3.362
     3.366     3.369     3.372     3.375     3.379     3.382     3.386     3.388     3.392     3.395
     3.399     3.402     3.406     3.409     3.413     3.416     3.420     3.423     3.427     3.430
     3.435     3.438     3.442     3.445     3.449     3.453     3.457     3.460     3.464     3.468
     3.472     3.475     3.479     3.483     3.486     3.491     3.494     3.498     3.502     3.506
     3.510     3.514     3.518     3.522     3.526     3.531     3.534     3.539     3.542     3.547
     3.551     3.555     3.559     3.564     3.567     3.572     3.576     3.581     3.584     3.589
     3.593     3.598     3.602     3.606     3.610     3.615     3.619     3.624     3.628     3.633
     3.637     3.642     3.646     3.651     3.655     3.660     3.664     3.669     3.673     3.678
     3.682     3.686     3.691     3.695     3.700     3.704     3.710     3.714     3.719     3.723
     3.728     3.733     3.738     3.742     3.747     3.752     3.757     3.761     3.766     3.771
     3.776     3.780     3.786     3.790     3.795     3.800     3.805     3.810     3.815     3.819
     3.825     3.829     3.835     3.839     3.845     3.849     3.855     3.859     3.865     3.869
     3.875     3.879     3.885     3.889     3.895     3.900     3.905     3.910     3.915     3.920
     3.926     3.930     3.935     3.941     3.945     3.951     3.956     3.961     3.966     3.972
     3.976     3.982     3.987     3.993     3.997     4.003     4.008     4.014     4.018     4.024
     4.029     4.035     4.039     4.045     4.050     4.056     4.061     4.066     4.071     4.077
     4.082     4.088     4.093     4.099     4.103     4.109     4.114     4.120     4.125     4.131
     4.136     4.142     4.147     4.153     4.157     4.163     4.168     4.174     4.179     4.185
     4.190     4.195     4.201     4.206     4.212     4.217     4.223     4.228     4.234     4.239
     4.245     4.250     4.256     4.261     4.267     4.272     4.278     4.283     4.289     4.294
     4.300     4.305     4.311     4.316     4.322     4.327     4.333     4.339     4.345     4.350
     4.356     4.361     4.367     4.372     4.378     4.383     4.389     4.394     4.400     4.405
     4.411     4.417     4.423     4.428     4.434     4.439     4.445     4.450     4.456     4.461
     4.467     4.473     4.478     4.484     4.489     4.495     4.500     4.506     4.511     4.517
     4.523     4.529     4.534     4.540     4.545     4.551     4.556     4.562     4.568     4.574
     4.579     4.585     4.590     4.596     4.601     4.607     4.613     4.619     4.624     4.630
     4.635     4.641     4.646     4.652     4.658     4.664     4.669     4.675     4.680     4.686
     4.691     4.697     4.703     4.709     4.714     4.720     4.725     4.731     4.736     4.741
** N:SNAPSHOT    TIME      DELT[S]
** WATER DEPTH [M]: (HP(L),L=2,LA)
      3600        0.00417   0.10000
     4.124     4.123     4.123     4.122     4.122     4.121     4.121     4.120     4.120     4.119
     4.118     4.117     4.117     4.116     4.116     4.115     4.115     4.114     4.114     4.114
     4.114     4.113     4.113     4.112     4.112     4.111     4.111     4.110     4.110     4.109
     4.109     4.109     4.109     4.108     4.108     4.107     4.107     4.106     4.107     4.106
     4.106     4.105     4.105     4.105     4.105     4.104     4.104     4.104     4.104     4.103
     4.103     4.103     4.102     4.102     4.102     4.102     4.101     4.102     4.101     4.101
     4.101     4.101     4.100     4.101     4.100     4.101     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100
     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100
     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.100     4.101
     4.100     4.101     4.100     4.101     4.101     4.101     4.101     4.102     4.101     4.102
     4.102     4.101     4.102     4.102     4.103     4.102     4.103     4.103     4.104     4.103
     4.104     4.104     4.105     4.104     4.105     4.105     4.106     4.106     4.107     4.106
     4.107     4.107     4.108     4.108     4.109     4.109     4.110     4.110     4.110     4.110
     4.111     4.111     4.112     4.112     4.113     4.113     4.114     4.114     4.115     4.115
     4.116     4.116     4.117     4.117     4.118     4.118     4.120     4.120     4.121     4.121
     4.122     4.122     4.122     4.123     4.123     4.125     4.125     4.126     4.126     4.127
     4.128     4.129     4.129     4.130     4.130     4.132     4.132     4.133     4.133     4.135
     4.135     4.136     4.137     4.138     4.138     4.139     4.140     4.141     4.141     4.143
     4.143     4.145     4.145     4.146     4.147     4.148     4.149     4.150     4.150     4.152
     4.152     4.154     4.154     4.156     4.156     4.158     4.158     4.160     4.160     4.162
     4.162     4.163     4.164     4.165     4.166     4.167     4.168     4.169     4.171     4.171
     4.173     4.173     4.175     4.176     4.177     4.178     4.180     4.180     4.182     4.183
     4.184     4.185     4.187     4.187     4.189     4.190     4.192     4.192     4.194     4.195
     4.197     4.197     4.199     4.200     4.202     4.203     4.204     4.205     4.207     4.208
     4.210     4.210     4.212     4.213     4.215     4.216     4.218     4.219     4.221     4.221
     4.223     4.224     4.225     4.227     4.228     4.230     4.231     4.233     4.234     4.236
     4.237     4.239     4.240     4.242     4.243     4.245     4.246     4.248     4.249     4.251
     4.252     4.254     4.255     4.257     4.258     4.260     4.262     4.264     4.265     4.267
     4.268     4.270     4.271     4.273     4.275     4.277     4.278     4.280     4.281     4.283
     4.285     4.287     4.288     4.290     4.291     4.294     4.295     4.297     4.298     4.301
     4.302     4.303     4.305     4.307     4.309     4.310     4.312     4.314     4.316     4.317
     4.320     4.321     4.323     4.325     4.327     4.328     4.331     4.332     4.334     4.336
     4.338     4.339     4.342     4.343     4.346     4.347     4.349     4.351     4.353     4.355
     4.357     4.359     4.361     4.362     4.365     4.366     4.369     4.370     4.373     4.374
     4.377     4.378     4.381     4.382     4.385     4.386     4.389     4.390     4.393     4.394
     4.397     4.398     4.400     4.402     4.404     4.406     4.408     4.411     4.412     4.415
     4.416     4.419     4.421     4.423     4.425     4.427     4.429     4.432     4.433     4.436
     4.437     4.440     4.442     4.444     4.446     4.449     4.450     4.453     4.455     4.457
     4.459     4.462     4.463     4.466     4.468     4.470     4.472     4.475     4.476     4.479
     4.481     4.484     4.485     4.488     4.490     4.492     4.494     4.497     4.499     4.501
     4.503     4.505     4.508     4.509     4.512     4.514     4.517     4.519     4.521     4.523
     4.526     4.528     4.530     4.532     4.535     4.537     4.540     4.541     4.544     4.546
     4.549     4.551     4.554     4.555     4.558     4.560     4.563     4.565     4.568     4.569
     4.572     4.574     4.577     4.579     4.582     4.584     4.586     4.588     4.591     4.593
     4.596     4.598     4.601     4.603     4.605     4.607     4.610     4.612     4.615     4.617
     4.620     4.622     4.624     4.627     4.628     4.631     4.633     4.636     4.638     4.641
     4.643     4.646     4.648     4.651     4.653     4.656     4.657     4.660     4.662     4.665
     4.667     4.670     4.672     4.675     4.677     4.680     4.682     4.685     4.687     4.690
     4.692     4.695     4.697     4.700     4.702     4.705     4.706     4.709     4.711     4.714
     4.716     4.719     4.721     4.724     4.726     4.729     4.731     4.734     4.736     4.741
```

Currently, I have data of 10 columns for each time. I want to create that as one single column of 500 data points. So, I want to arrange the data columns such that first the data on row 1 will be used and then data on second row and so on. This way, we will have one column for one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces a matrix, `result`, containing the times in the first row and the data in columns underneath the corresponding time.

```
L <- readLines(infile)

nt <- length(grep("TIME", L)) # no. of TIME lines
nd <- round((length(L) / nt) - 3) # no. of data lines per time

# times
ix.times <- rep(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), c(2, 1, nd))
times <- scan(text = L[ix.times]) [ c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) ]

# data
ix.dat <- rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), c(3, nd))
dat <- matrix(scan(text = L[ix.dat]), nc = nt)

result <- rbind(times, dat)
```

The first few rows are:

```
> head(result)
         [,1]    [,2]
times 0.00208 0.00417
      3.22400 4.12400
      3.22100 4.12300
      3.22000 4.12300
      3.21700 4.12200
      3.21600 4.12200
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I am still trying to understand your code.

Comment: @ G.Grothendieck: I have another quick question. If I have data such that each rows doesn't have equal number of values then what can I do ? Right now you are using the condition of count ==10. What happens if one line has 5 and rest of the lines have 10 data? This might happen in future when I will have more data.

Comment: Have changed it so that it only depends on knowing that there are 50 rows in each data section and 500 data values in each data section.

Comment: Thank you for modifying the code. It seems in your new code you don't have a variable `cnt` but you have that variable on the command for `dat`. May be you forgot to modify that line.

Comment: Have fixed. We don't need `cnt` any more.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question : On idea  to remove the comments lines is to use recycling. First, I read all the data using `fill=TRUE` then:

```
dat <- read.table(file=file.Name,fill=TRUE)
```

Then, since you have fixed number of rows, you can do this :

```
dat <- dat[c(rep(FALSE,3),rep(TRUE,500)),]
```

You will get a clean data.frame .

I don't get your second part of the question.

Comment: Hi, Agstudy thanks for that piece of code. What I want is to create a data frame with the time as the header and the data as the columns. So, for each time I have one set of data and that will go on one column. For second time I will have another data and that will go on another column. In the sample data, I have two times. If you look on second data of third row of the header for data sets, then it is the time that I want as the header of the column. I hope I made it clear now.

Comment: Currently, I have data of 10 columns for each time. I want to create that as one single column of 500 data points. So, I want to arrange the data columns such that first the data on row 1 will be used and then data on second row and so on. This way, we will have one column for one time.

Comment: @Jdbaba create some `matrix` or `data.frame` (let's say called `d`) and look at the result of `as.vector(t(d))`.

Answer (score 1):

**Second part solution:**

First, call the sample data as `sample`. I assume two columns in the solution below. You can use `lapply`to apply to other columns.

```
col.1<-as.data.frame(sample[,1])
col.2<-as.data.frame(sample[,2])

Now col.1 and col.2 are dataframes. Try to have the same colnames for `rbind` to work.

sample.1<-rbind(col.1,col.2)
```